# Xcode bindings: can not add object to NSArrayController

Tags: xcode, core-data, data-binding

I have an entity **Axis** with relationship [to many] to entity **AxisValues**.

And I try to add **AxisValue** object to selected object **Axis**. I bind one NSArrayController *Axes* to ManagedObjectContext, entity **Axis**. The second NSArrayController *Selected Axis Values* with entity **AxisValue** is bind by ContentSet to *Axes*, ControllerKey *selection*, ModelKeyPath *axisValues*.

In interface it works nice, in a NSTableView I have proper values. But I cannot add or remove **AxisValue** objects by action **add:** or **remove:** connected to *Selected Axis Values* controller.

How to bind *Selected Axis Values* to have possibility to add and remove objects by actions **add:** and **remove:**?

Comment: Did you bind Managed Object Context? What happens when you do `add:`?

Comment: Few times. But this time it was disconnected. Thank You!